The .edmx file is not executed in the project written with EF & SQL Server Compact in C#
I am using SQL Server Compact v4 in the project and I have completed the project with a database-first approach. I am using Entity Framework with the EntityFramework.Sql Server, EntityFramwework.SqlServerCompact, ErikEJ.SqlCE40 libraries,  I have also installed SQL Server Compact Toolbox, but when I click on the .edmx file, it does not show me the tables and gives the following error:

Error 175: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.

At the same time, the project runs but does not open the desired file.
Even in the toolbox section, the "Add Sql Server Compact 4 Connection..." and "Add Sql Server Compact 3 Connection..." options are disabled.



What version of net/core are you using and what is the target version?   Make sure you do a clean build which forces all the source code to get recompiled.  EDMX is a mapping file that was used to map the c# classes/properties to the database tables/fields.  It is no longer used which may be the reason for the error.  I would run a migration to create a new mapping.  You may be using an older version of Net and having compatibility issues with the drivers that are used to communicate with the database.  The version of Net, drivers, and database all have to be compatible.

You need VS 2010 to do that. Get rid of the EDMX and use code first from Database instead

You also need to install the SQL CE provider MSI to use it with the toolbox
